# Extend GPL v3 software with library under other license

Tags: gpl-3

The [Signal Mobile app for iOS](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-iOS) for messaging is licensed under [GPL Version 3](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-iOS/blob/master/LICENSE).

Would it be permissible to implement some add-on library (some new authentication mechanism, say) under a different license (perhaps not even open source), and publish a modified version of the mobile app still that links against that library. In effect, the modified mobile app would contain the as software under a different license; but it would still honor GPL v3 as "container" (and it would have to do so under the rules of this license)?

Just wondering. I cannot think of a reason right now why such a combined scheme would not be permissible under the license terms of this mobile app in particular (and GPLv3 in general). Is there a general term for this kind of arrangement?

**UPDATE** Here is a more detailed description of a possible use case in reaction to a question that was raised as comment:

Consider my team has developed a new [FIDO3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIDO2_Project) library that uses novel "brainometric" sensors for authentication. For instance, when a user thinks the thought "Yes, I want to log in", the FIDO3 library can reliably determine that the thought originated in the user's brain and was based on a voluntary decision. Obviously, the FIDO3 library has to do a lot of fancy signal processing of EEG data to make this happen, so this is stuff that I may not want to open-source yet, let alone under GPL v3. (So far the concrete example is a joke, of course, but I hope it makes the general point clearer.)

Now I want to ship a modified version of the Signal app that supports FIDO3 authentication. For instance, the modified version will have to come with some new display element that says "Please think the following to log in ...". My understanding is that the code for this new app has to remain as open source and under GPL v3. So presumably there would be a project `rookie099/Signal-iOS` on GitHub where one could e.g. `grep "Please think"` without obstacles. The code in that project would also have to call out to and link (in some manner) with the FIDO3 library, in order for the modified app to function.

So my question with respect to this specific example is: granted that the code for the modified version of the Signal app remains under GPL v3, can it call out (link against) the FIDO3 library even if that one remains under a different license (and is perhaps not even published as open source.) So if it does, can I still publish the modified app? I suspect the answer will be yes, because the Signal app presumably already relies on a whole range of libraries with different licensing schemes (including libraries belonging iOS itself.) But then I don't know for sure, nor do I know the right "language" to describe this situation in IT-legal terms, hence this question. (Clear enough now?)

Comment: Are you asking if GPLv3 software can be linked to other software, and the result distributed under some other licence than GPLv3?

Comment: @MadHatter Not that's not my question. FWIK the  to obvious answer to that one would be no and I would not want to pursue such a course. I'll add a more concrete example to the question which hopefully makes the point clearer.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that that was, in fact, exactly what you were asking.

Comment: @MadHatter IMHO it's not for you to tell me what I was asking. Anyway, I got my answer now (including a downvote, so what).

Comment: With respect, the answer you accepted answers the question "*can I combine GPLv3 software with other software, and release the result under anything other than GPLv3*".  Since you accepted it, it's not unreasonable to conclude that that is the question you were asking.  I'm very glad, though, that you got an answer you were happy with.

Comment: @MadHatter Thanks for your reasonable response. My previous comment may have been unnecessarily sharp in tone. Sorry for that and all settled now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So my question with respect to this specific example is: granted that the code for the modified version of the Signal app remains under GPL v3, can it call out (link against) the FIDO3 library even if that one remains under a different license (and is perhaps not even published as open source.) So if it does, can I still publish the modified app?

The GPL license requires that *all* code in the application is made available under the GPL or a compatible open-source license. The only exception is the code that comes with the operating system.

As your FIDO3 library is not part of iOS, the combination of the closed-source FIDO3 library and the GPL license Signal application violates the requirements of the GPL license and cannot be legally distributed.

Answer (score 2):

You can distribute derivative works of the Signal app as long as they are under GPLv3.

Including your version that includes a copy of FIDO3_Brainometry. You can distribute that app under GPLv3.

You can't distribute it under any other license, except AGPLv3 as mentioned in section 13 of GPLv3.

However, you'd need the permission of the authors of FIDO3_Brainometry as well, not just the permission of the authors of the Signal app. If it's closed-source, that's the same as saying they don't give you permission to distribute it as GPLv3. So they can sue you for copyright infringement.

If you own the copyright to FIDO3_Brainometry, then of course you already have permission. You still have to use GPLv3 or AGPLv3 so as not to infringe the copyright of the Signal app.

---

You must distribute your derived work under the GPL:

> You may convey a work based on the Program, or the modifications to produce it from the Program, in the form of source code under the terms of section 4, provided that you also meet all of these conditions:
>
> a) The work must carry prominent notices stating that you modified it, and giving a relevant date.
> b) The work must carry prominent notices stating that it is released under this License and any conditions added under section 7. This requirement modifies the requirement in section 4 to “keep intact all notices”.
> c) **You must license the entire work, as a whole, under this License to anyone who comes into possession of a copy. This License will therefore apply, along with any applicable section 7 additional terms, to the whole of the work, and all its parts, regardless of how they are packaged. This License gives no permission to license the work in any other way**, but it does not invalidate such permission if you have separately received it.
> d) If the work has interactive user interfaces, each must display Appropriate Legal Notices; however, if the Program has interactive interfaces that do not display Appropriate Legal Notices, your work need not make them do so.

Comment: As I understand the question, the OP *is* the rightsholder for what you term FIDO3_Brainometry.

Comment: @MadHatter Well then he can give himself permission to distribute FIDO3_Brainometry under GPLv3.

Comment: I completely agree, though I think the question was not "*can I do that*, but rather "*I don't want to do that, do I have to*".

Comment: Yes, in that example the OP (that's me) is the rightsholder (even though FIDO3_Brainometry is a hypothetical example.) Could someone perhaps quote the specific language (sentence) in GPLv3 that determines this case (a party wanting to keep its library closed source yet still serving in modified GPLv3 software). Or is it  perhaps subject to different interpretations of more general language (such as "combine")? I'm not trying to "escape" the rules, just trying to understand them in better detail. +1 if such a specific quote arrives in this response.

Comment: @rookie099 okay, I quoted the part where works based on GPLv3-licensed programs have to be GPLv3-licensed